# Drawer layout placement?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

Total beginner with Android, just learning how things work. I have a map app with a autocomplete search. I want to put a Drawer with a Listview in the app, so the user can access some options. Like a button or something to the left of the autocomplete search. Looking at http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html for this.

Can't find where in the layout to place the DrawerLayout, no matter where i put it, it doesn't play with the autocomplete fragment or the map fragment. 
Anyone know here to place it in the main xml layout?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/place_autocomplete_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment" />

</RelativeLayout>

        <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MapsActivity" />
   </LinearLayout>
```

Cheers!

Comment: Anyone have any suggestions?